# ZEROMQ with hundreds of peers to the same socket

Tags: c++, sockets, stream, zeromq

I'm thinking of using ZeroMQ STREAM sockets (version 4) to talk to hundreds of raw TCP clients.  I'm wondering whether ZMQ copes with this or if it impacts performance/reliability.

Although I'm proposing using STREAM sockets,the question should apply to any socket type that is accepting larger numbers of peers.

The guide and specifications don't really cover this, apart from a brief mention in the Major-domo pattern that it's designed for hundreds of clients.

Does anyone have experience?

I'm going to be using the C libzmq library and targeting *nix and Windows.

Comment: Are you still looking into this, or did you end up trying it? Also, did you use C or C++?